# Distance Calculations in Android?

Tags: android, distance, google-places-api

I am very new to android Google maps i write the code for find distance between two places:

private String getDistance(final String start, final String end) {

```
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
     float distance = 0.0f;
               StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=");
                 url.append(start.replace(" ", "").trim().toString());
                 url.append("&destination=");
                 url.append(end.replace(" ", "").trim().toString());
                 url.append("&mode=transit");
                 url.append("&language=en-EN");
                 url.append("&sensor=false");



                 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url.toString());
                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                 String line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
                 JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs");

                 for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                     distance  = Float.valueOf(obj.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text").replace("km", ""));
                     System.out.println("Distance == " + obj.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text").replace("km", ""));
                 }


              BigDecimal   kmVal = BigDecimal.valueOf(distance);
              System.out.println("===========distance=============="+kmVal);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
                }).start();

            return distance  ;

    }
```

I am getting the Distance with differences of 30 km. I am getting 30 km extra instead of actual distance.

Comment: The first thing you should do is separate out the different responsibilities in your code...fetching the data and calculating distance should be separate concerns. Then try running in the debugger

Comment: ok how can i get currect distance?

Comment: by breaking the problem down, and debugging...like I just mentioned...

Comment: my concern  is i am getting distance in km but with 30k extara distance?

Comment: my concern is you are not listening to advice.

Comment: So separate the code into two methods.  One to get the data and one to calculate the distance then debug.  Just like Mitch says.

Comment: you need to learn about threads, first. Why do you use a Thread, what do you expect will happen with your program, what does final mean, and then, what is the actual distance, how do you know the output is wrong ...

Comment: sorry for that i will fallow ur instructions

Comment: While we are raising concerns, I have one too. What's up with asking the same question, not once, not twice, but counting this one, **4 times**? [First](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13206451/450534), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13208501/450534) and [Third](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13208946/450534). They all seem to be different, but essentially, for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this links it will Defiantly helps you.

- [How to calculate distance between two locations using their longitude and latitude value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu)
- [Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)
- [Distance between two map point or lat long in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813828/distance-between-two-map-point-or-lat-long-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to query the google maps to get the distance between two places. If you know the latitude and longitude of both places you can just construct `Location` objects and use it's `distanceTo()` method which will give you the exact distance in meters.

```
Location from = new Location("");
from.setLatitude(yourStartLatitude);
from.setLongitude(yourStartLongitude);

Location to = new Location("");
to.setLatitude(yourEndLatitude);
to.setLongitude(yourEndLongitude);

float distance = from.distanceTo(to); // The distance in meters
```

Comment: by this i am getting 514625.25 these type of values i am getting ?

Comment: that means 514625 m = 514,6 km

Comment: that is not actual distance suppose hyderabad to chennai is 620km but based on this wrong?

Comment: This is the distance in a straight line, not on roads. If that's what you are after, you shouldn't use this method. If you just want to know the exact distance, then this is it.

Comment: ok thanks for your help by this  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=

Comment: getting the exact distance how can i use in my requirement ?

Comment: To be picky, the distance returned is along a great circle, not a straight line.

Comment: is there another possibility to find distance using alt and lang positions ?